# How do I reset my repository to a certain release and apply all my changes from that point on?

Tags: git

I made a big mistake and I want to know how to recover from it. Several weeks ago, I cloned a repository, branched off master and started making changes. It wasn't until today that I realized that my modifications were being made to the upcoming release, not the current one. Unfortunately, the person who created the project only uses tags for releases and not separate branches.

So far, I've been able to branch off of the current release by checking out the appropriate tag and creating a new branch.  The problem is that I want to replay all *my* specific changes on top of the new branch. In other words, I don't want any new code since the last release, only changes I've made.

Going forward, how do I work with the remote repo but prevent the pulls from upgrading my code to a new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`git rebase --onto`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). I grabbed this example directly from git man page and replaced the branch name with what I understand from your question:

```
                        H---I---J current_branch
                       /
              E---F---G  master
             /
A---B---C---D  old_release
```

You regret branched off from `master` when you should have done it on `old_release`

In this case, you should do:

```
git rebase --onto old_release master current_branch
```

That should replay your commit from `H` to `J` on `old_release` branch.

Comment: Dang! You bang Mr, Kang! You made it so easy to understand.  Thanks.

Comment: As I asked, going forward, what should I do to keep pulls from clobbering my code? Should I disconnect from the remote repo, keep a separate branch or something else?

Comment: @user148298 If you are the sole person working on the specific branch, doing pulls from remote will not clobber your code as long as you don't merge with the wrong branch. If you plan to touch a lot files on your feature branch and would cause conflicts when merging with master, it might be worthwhile to keep a separate branch based on master and consistently update it with your changes. Otherwise, I would just pull from master when I am ready.

Answer (score -1):

```
git rm -r .
git checkout HEAD~3 .
git commit
```

Where HEAD~3 is where you want to come back to.
You could also no

```
git reset --hard <tag/branch/commit id>
```

Then, you make you're changes again :/

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain what each command does. Not everyone uses and understands all of the command-line syntax. Are you telling me that I have to manually add all my changes by hand? I have a hard time believing it.